# Sql consume date with day before

Tags: java, sql, spring, jackson

So I'm writing some REST API and one of my entity has a java.util.Date type; My POST endpoint consumes JSON type, something like this:

```
{
   "authorId": 7845,
   "authorName": {
      "first": "Dan",
      "second": "Brown"
   },
   "birth": {
      "date": "1987-10-25",
      "country": "USA",
      "city": "New York"
   },
   "description": "Very good author!"
}
```

Also I override jackson deserialize method to handle invalid date format and everything that involves this:

```
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDate> {
    public CustomDateDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public CustomDateDeserializer(Class t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException {
        String date = jp.getValueAsString();

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate parsed;

        try {
            parsed = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new InvalidDateTypeException(jp.currentName(), jp.getText());
        }

        return parsed;
    }
}
```

In my DTO model I use exactly this deserializer for this parameter:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
@PastOrPresent(message = "Value 'date' must be past or present!")
private LocalDate date;
```

During life of all my intermediate objects (models and DTOs) this value everywhere looks like in input JSON - 1987-10-25.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/author/new", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> addNewAuthor(@RequestBody @Valid AuthorPostDto postAuthor) {
    AuthorPostDto response = authorService.addNewAuthor(postAuthor);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Service method:

```
public AuthorPostDto addNewAuthor(AuthorPostDto author) {
    if (authorRepository.existsByAuthorId(author.getAuthorId())) {
        throw new AuthorAlreadyExistsException();
    }

    Author toPost = toModelMapper.mapAuthorDtoToAuthor(author);
    Author response = authorRepository.save(toPost);
    return toDtoMapper.mapAuthorModelToDto_POST(response);
}
```

All objects - postAuthor(parsed by Jackson in Controller), toPost, response and returned value from service - contains Date value like in input JSON - 1987-10-25.

But in SQL and in returned value from controller date appear with the day before: 1987-10-24...

How to fix this??

Comment: Could be a problem with default time zones or offsets. Does the database store the date in UTC? Does it store it as a Date or DateTime or even as a Timestamp?

Comment: @deHaar yes! Think problem is exactly with that. My time zone is -2 hours. Throughout whole life of this object inside java app date is 1987-10-25, but without time stamp. When object leave app it converts to 1987-10-25 00:00:00. And after that use my time zone. So I get 1987-10-24 22:00:00. As my data base save only date it get only 1987-10-24. Thinks, it works in this way

Comment: Then you should make sure you correctly convert from and to UTC in Java while you store date times in your database in UTC only.